# How to show alert for slow internet in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to detect slow internet in ionic2 app and handle it.

I have done google and approach to use settimeout is perferred but how can I use it when calling an api ?

I am calling api as:

```
   AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT = is a constant having api url.

 this.returned = this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}login`, "email=" + email + "&password=" + password, { headers: headers }).timeout(100).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

            this.conn_error_msg = '';

            if (data.status == 200) {


            }
            else {

            }

        }, 
        error => {
            this.isDisabled = 0;
            this.conn_error_msg = 'Internet connection error. Please try again.';
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
            loader.dismiss();
        }
        );
```

My timeout is working fine using this way but i am in need to show an alert ..

Here i wish to show an alert if time out

Solved:

```
this.http.get(url)
```

.timeout(1000)
  .map(...)
  .subcribe((success) => {...}, (err) => { // Deal here with timeout error. });

Hope it helps someone.

Happy coding.

Comment: You can use rxjs timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timeout when calling the api like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

return this.http.get(yourUrl).timeout(50000, new Error('Timeout!'));
```

Of course, the same can be done when using the post/put... methods as well.

Comment: Error function expects type Scheduler. I'm getting this error:

Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Scheduler'. Property 'SchedulerAction' is missing in type 'Error'

Comment: @sebaferreras: i used it as :: this.http.post(`${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}login`, "email=" + email + "&password=" + password, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).timeout(50000, new Error('Timeout!')).subscribe(data => {

Comment: using so i am getting : Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: @NarendraVyas try like this `this.http.post(...).timeout(...).map(...)`. The `timeout` should be first and then the `.map(...)`.

Comment: @IgorJanković, can you please add the most relevant parts of your code or open a new question? That way we'd be able to see what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: thanks @sebaferreras  now i am not getting this error, i have to also use import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'; but  i am exploring how to show am alert to user to refresh page in case of error .. thanks again

Comment: That's great! :) I've updated the answer with the import statement. If you want, please add the most relevant parts of your code, and we can take a look at how to display an alert in that case.

Comment: @sebaferreras : can you please see my updated question, thanks in advance

Comment: @sebaferreras : can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930623/ionic2-cancel-api-request-if-timeout ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
let returned = false;

startCallTime(slowConnectionLimit){
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(returned){
      // IS NOT SLOW
    } else {
      // IS SLOW. SHOW YOUR MESSAGE
    }
  }, slowConnectionLimit)
}

callApi = () => {
 startCallTime(30000); // WILL DETECT SLOW CONNECTION AFTER 30 SECONDS
 this.http.get().then((res) => {
    returned = true; // HERE YOU KNOW IF THE CALL HAS ENDED
 });
}
```

I think @sebaferreras answer is more clean, but is only useful to rxjs...